# how to make the relationship between velocity and time be linear by python

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created code which making  turtlebot 2 following me depend on detecting my face and chose a value of velocity 0.2 m/s

my issue is the movement of the robot when disappearing my face suddenly which making turtlebot stops suddenly, I need to make decreasing its velocity gradually like this figure [link text](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=linear+velocity+with+time&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi754nI8_HgAhXCxbwKHRJ3D_gQ_AUIDigB&biw=1855&bih=952#imgrc=fbTRSzhfqRk8uM:)

my experience not good in ROS

I need to change the line  `self.twist.linear.x = 0.05` by the linear relationship between velocity and time as shown in the figure in the link, I mean that turtlebot will stop after a certain time, for example, 20 second

my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python



import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import cv2, cv_bridge


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/redhwan/1/run-webcam/Face-Detect-Demo-by-Ali-master/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' )


class Face_detection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = cv_bridge.CvBridge()

        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/usb_cam/image_raw',Image, self.image_callback)
        self.cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop',Twist, queue_size=1)
        self.twist = Twist()
        
    
    def image_callback(self, msg):
        image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg,desired_encoding='bgr8')

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale( gray,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(30, 30),flags=cv2.cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

        if(type(faces) != tuple):
            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
           
                 cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
     

                 self.twist.linear.x = 0.2

                 self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)
             
        
            cv2.imshow('face ', image)
                

            cv2.waitKey(3)
             

         

        if(type(faces) == tuple):
            self.twist.linear.x = 0.05
            self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)
                           
        
rospy.init_node('face_detection')
follower = Face_detection()
rospy.spin()
```

please help me or any suggestion

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317979/how-to-make--the-relationship-between-velocity-and-time-be-linear-by-python/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have two ways of doing this :

- By calculations :

You have to define the acceleration you want (well in your case this is a deceleration). Taking your example, you want to go from `0.2 m/s` to `0.05 m/s` in `20 seconds` meaning you have `dv = -0.15` and `dt = 20`. (`dv = vfinal - vinitial` that's why it's negative). Since `a = dv/dt` you know you want a **constant** acceleration of `-0.0075 m/s²` (or a deceleration of `0.0075 m/s²`).

Now if you integrate the equation of the acceleration and assume the acceleration is **constant** you get `v = a * t + K` (`K` is another constant from the integration). You know `v(t=0)=0.2` so you have `v = a * 0 + K = 0.2 => K = 0.2.`
You also know that `a = -0.0075` so that's it you have the linear relationship between velocity and time :

```
v = -0.0075 * t + 0.2
```

- Another option is to use a `velocity smoother` which basically do all those calculations for you. You can set limits for the acceleration and velocity. There is a package compatible with the turtlebot (with the mobile base `kobuki` to be accurate) : [yocs_velocity_smoother](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_velocity_smoother). You will need to use a launch file with a `nodelet manager` and define a `yaml` file to set your parameters and then call the `nodelet`. I can give you a launch file example if you want.

---

**Edit :**

> I tried to solve by the first way, my
> issue is in how to find (t,t0) in
> python with rospy because of lacking
> my experience in ROS

You will need to save the starting time when you start decelerating and then just substract the current time to get the value for `t`. It can be done like that :

```
#global variable outside your callback
starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec()
save_time = True 
...
if(save_time == True):
    save_time = False  #Condition only the first time
    starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec() #save the current time
now = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec()
t = now - starting_time           
self.twist.linear.x = -0.0075 * t + 0.2
self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)
```

For the second method you can go to the wiki I've linked and select the `indigo` version, I just saw that there is no documentation for the `melodic` distribution. Moreover you can see an example by looking at [standalone.launch](https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_ocs/blob/devel/yocs_velocity_smoother/launch/standalone.launch) and check the `standalone.yaml` file too. This package allows you to set speed limits and acceleration limits so with your example you don't have to change your code, just to use the `velocity_smoother_nodelet` and set the parameter `accel_lim_v` to `0.0075`.

**Edit 2:**

> I need to recount from zero when lost my face

You just need to reset your flag `save_time` when you don't see the face anymore with an else condition for example :

```
if(type(faces) == tuple):
    if(save_time == True):
        save_time = False  #Condition only the first time
        starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec() #save the current time
    now = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec()
    t = now - starting_time           
    self.twist.linear.x = -0.0075 * t + 0.2
    self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)
else:
    save_time = True
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-08**:
first of all, thank you so much for your answer

I tried to solve by the first way, my issue is in how to find (t,t0) in python with rospy because of lacking my experience in ROS

I am confusing, I tried to understand it from this code (http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials/Moving%20in%20a%20Straight%20Line)
but failed

the second way is ambiguous for me

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-08**:
Thank you so much to help me,
the output after `27 second` and `5.3 m` which assume that the speed becomes zero:
0.199999976754,
...,
...,
...,
0.199999955297

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-08**:
What are those numbers ? To make it clear you should edit your question to add your new code.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-08**:
sorry, if I make any mistake in my question

those number is `vfinal`  to my turtlebot 2 after `27 sec`

to clear:

my question  after `20 sec` ....>  `vfinal =0.05 m/s` also in `0 sec`  ....> `vfinal =0.2  m / s=vinitial`   as you  mention above

this my figure [link text](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=linear+velocity+with+time&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi754nI8_HgAhXCxbwKHRJ3D_gQ_AUIDigB&biw=1855&bih=952#imgrc=fbTRSzhfqRk8uM:)

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-08**:
I can't help without seeing how you got those results. Please provide your code.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-08**:
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

```
        self.twist.linear.x = 0.2

        self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)
         
    
    cv2.imshow('face ', image)
            

    cv2.waitKey(3)
         

     

    if(type(faces) == tuple):
        starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec()
        save_time = True
        if(save_time == True):
            save_time = False  #Condition only the first time
            starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec() #save the current time
        now = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec()
        t = now - starting_time           
        v = self.twist.linear.x = -0.0075 * t + 0.2
        print v
        self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)
```

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-08**:
sorry, I can't write full code in one comment because of the number of characters

rest code the same above

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-09**:
I am very sorry, my mistake that I  put `starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec() & save_time = True` inside my callback

The outputs now are good but another issue has emerged, Once the speed reaches zero, then start to increase.

I need to stop it.

thank you @delb to help me

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-09**:
It is fine now, after using if t > , < , = with  a number

Thank you so much @Delb

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-11**:
unfortunately, it is fine for the first time.
my purpose from this question not solved yet, why???
once  run the code,`starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec() save_time = True` start count of the second, this is fine for me, but I need to recount from zero when lost my face.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-11**:
You just need another condition to reset your flags. You should have a flag like `face_found` that is true when you've found a face and set it to false once the face is lost. Then in a conditon checking if face_found is true or false you can reset the flag `save_time` so that when `face_found` is true again you correctly save the starting time again.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-03-11**:
thank you so much@delb,In my code `if(type(faces) != tuple):` this mean `face_found`
and `if(type(faces) == tuple):` this mean `face_lost`
I tried but failed

please @Delb help me